# Setting specific time for cron job and then intervals

Tags: linux, cron

I was wondering if with cron, after I set a specific date for the task to run can I then specify it to run in intervals of a specific amount of days from that point on.

For example: I know you can do */2 * * * *  to run every 2 minutes

But is it possible to have say 0 0 15 4 * run a file and then subsequently run every X days?

i.e Run on X day and then every 20 days after

Im thinking I may need 2 crons for this, where the second one is initialized when the first is set?  Thus creating the */20 paramater in the crontab file?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to write a wrapper script that does some time-stamp magic and checks when whatever you want to run every twenty days was last run successfully.

Cron doesn't offer any support for what you're after.

Have cron execute the wrapper daily.

Comment: I handled this script level with PHP and just checked nightly with cron to hit the file that sent the messages.